# dvipng error when using htlatex on eps file. includegraphics Unrecoverable error 36096

Tags: errors, png, wolfram-mathematica, htlatex

I am hoping someone here can give me a hint about this error. I am not really sure this is latex problem, but part of the software that I am using to process the latex document.

The setup is very simple. one eps file of a plot created from Mathematica software and then exported to eps.

One tex file that includes this graphics file. I want to make HTML of this using htlatex.

```
\documentclass[10pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \includegraphics{mma_e1}
\end{document}
```

The eps file is valid, in the sense that I can open it using many apps and view it. gsview, etc..

I can run latex fine on it, and looking at the file .ps file, the image is there. pdflatex also work. Image is in the final pdf file.

Only `htlatex foo.tex` gives this error, in dvipng processing

```
>htlatex foo.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
.....
System call: dvipng -T tight -x 1400 -D 72 -bg Transparent -pp 1:1 foo.idv 
-o foo0x.png
This is dvipng 1.14 Copyright 2002-2010 Jan-Ake Larsson
dvipng warning: DVI magnification of 1000 over-ridden by user (1400) 
GPL Ghostscript 9.06: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
--- Warning --- System return: 36096
Entering foo.css
Entering foo.tmp
```

So, I am not sure why this error happens on this one .eps file generated by Mathematica.

Other eps files work with no problem with htlatex. I mean other eps files generated by other apps. Only the images exported by Mathematica to eps seem to give htlatex a problem.

Is it possible the type of eps file generated by Mathematica is not supported by dvipng?

Is this a problem with dvipng or with Mathematica not generating eps files with the right format? But then why I can open the eps file just fine with other applications?

I have put the above tex file and the .eps file in this folder at my site if someone would like to give it a try http://12000.org/tmp/v6/

When I open the eps file using text editor, it looks a little strange, as it seems to have some non-ascii chars in it,in the first line. But this is how it was generated. Here is a screen shot of top of the eps file.

[image]

The question is: What is the cause of this error from dvipng?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not pure *.EPS, but EPS with a preview. If you remove the text before %!PS-Adobe (and after %%EOF, if exists), all should work fine. And in the future you should generate EPS files without preview.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know there was eps with preview and one without it. I was simply using the Mathematica UI, and selecting the image on the screen, then right-click and selecting save as EPS. There was no option for preview or no preview. I changed now the way I am exporting the image and instead of using the UI and the mouse, now I export the image using the command `Export["mma_e1.eps", plot]` and now the eps file worked fine with htlatex ! the preview part is gone. (How a user was supposed to know this difference?). Now I know and will export images using the export command from now on.

Comment: Having the same issues as well.  Have many .pdf and some .eps in my converted_graphics folder, and very few are being picked up.  There is an error message during run time of tex4ht, error #4, which is occurring for each .eps.  My guess is that text4ht by default does not see .eps, or cannot handle them?