# Why does \hat{} create whitespace following its appearance with tex4ht?

Tags: tex4ht, white-space

I noticed that in the html output from a tex4ht run, there are spaces after the `\hat{}`.   However, in the dvips output, there are no spaces.

Is there a workaround for this? My guess is there needs to be a web-based amsmath file used.

[image]

**(Modified)**

After looking at @michal.h21's suggestion to use `pic-m` the results are outstanding.  Below is the command line, and lower is the preamble. Using `{xhtml}` in the preamble alone worked well, and if `{xhtml,mathml}` is used, the images are not produced.

```
htlatex test.tex "myfile.cfg,charset=utf-8,pic-m" " -utf8 -cunihft"
```

and here is the preamble (contents of myfile.cfg):

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\Configure{Picture}{.svg}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{14}{10}{8}
\ConfigureEnv{tabular}
    {\HCode{}}{\HCode{}}{}{}
\ConfigureEnv{figure} 
    {\HCode{}}{\HCode{}}{}{}    
\Configure{float}
   {\ifOption{refcaption}{}{\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar \leavevmode}}
   {\HCode{}}
{\ifvmode \IgnorePar \fi\EndP \HCode{}\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar}
\Css {body {margin-top: 100px;
                 margin-right: 400px;
                 margin-bottom: 10px;
                 margin-left: 400px;
                }
         }
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Comment: Just to make sure your code isn't written in an unsual way, could you add the relevant lines of code to your question?

Comment: Sure, here's the code:  `$\hat{t}_c = \exp(y_c)/\sum
\exp(y_l)$` and `$E_c=0.5(\hat{t}_c- t_c)^2$`

Comment: I did try encapsulating the above in-line equations with `\( ... \)` and it looked better.   Of course the issue in the OP only occured when I was outputting to html and using .svg images for equations.   When I use `\Preamble{xhtml, mathml}` and comment out the .svg command, the issues in the OP don't arise.  However, the summation symbols from `\sum` are very large in the output xhtml,mathml results(?)

Comment: @4k3x9d7r try the `pic-m` option. it converts all inline math to pictures, which is better than the default method. other possible options are "mathjax" or "mathml,mathjax", which looks best in most circumstances, but requires JavaScript

Comment: @michal.h21, thanks, see the modified post, since I added the preamble and command line that produced the best results I have seen thus far.  FYI- I did change the .png equation images to .svg, since .png are hazy and low res.   Do I want to use {xhtml,mathml} in the pre-amble or just {xhtml) -- which seems to do fine without mathml?

Comment: I figured it out, using both `{xhtml,mathml}` in the preamble will kiil the equation images from being produced.  So I will go with `{xhtml}` by itself in the preamble.

Comment: @4k3x9d7r, yes, `mathml` disables pictures for math, so you want to use `pic-m` and similar options, see http://cvr.cc/?p=504 for more `pic-` variants

Comment: @michal.h21 - thanks, works like a charm.  However, for a book, even though I am using `\usepackage{titlesec}` and `\usepackage{titletoc}`, the compiler does not like \tableofcontents, so I just type S to continue and it worked out.   However, I am now chasing down why "PIC" is showing where there should be pictures, and the compiler is throwing an error when trying to convert the .eps files in the converted image folder.

Comment: @michal.h21 - I did notice the post at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112863/dvipng-error-when-using-htlatex-on-eps-file-includegraphics-unrecoverable-error, so should I focus on that?

Comment: @4k3x9d7r maybe don't use `titletoc` and `titlesec` packages with `tex4ht`, you can include them only optionally using `\ifdefined\HCode\else .... \fi` in the preamble. regarding the images, you can try to compile them to SVG or PNG first using imagemagick or some other available command, if you don't use `.eps` extension in the `\includegraphics` commands.

Comment: @michal.h21 - thanks, will try using .eps as an extension for the pictures throwing error message #4.

Comment: @michal.h21 - I created a new OP for this .eps issue (at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495031/tex4ht-not-converting-eps-images-in-converted-graphics-folder-to-png-or-svg ), since the \hat{} problem was resolved by going to xhtml and using `pic-m`. Didn't want to cross post or mix issues.