# tex4ht not converting .eps images in converted_graphics folder to .png or .svg

Tags: errors, tex4ht, eps, htlatex, includegraphics

Inside the latex file (.tex) the typical picture command is used:

```
\includegraphics[bb=0 0 2100 1528,width=3.83in,height=2.79in,keepaspectratio]{summbetadiethist.eps}
```

However, when running htlatex with the command:

```
htlatex foo.tex "myfile.cfg,charset=utf-8,pic-m" " -utf8 -cunihft"
```

there are error messages thrown like:

[image]

The preamble (myfile.cfg contents) are as follows:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.pdf,.svg,.png,.jpg}
\Configure{Picture}{.svg}
\ifdefined\HCode\else .... \fi
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{14}{10}{8}
\ConfigureEnv{tabular}
    {\HCode{}}{\HCode{}}{}{}
\ConfigureEnv{figure} 
    {\HCode{}}{\HCode{}}{}{}    
\Configure{float}
   {\ifOption{refcaption}{}{\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar \leavevmode}}
   {\HCode{}}
{\ifvmode \IgnorePar \fi\EndP \HCode{}\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar}
\Css {body {margin-top: 100px;
                 margin-right: 400px;
                 margin-bottom: 10px;
                 margin-left: 400px;
                }
         }
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

If the .svg line in the preamble is commented out to enforce creation of .png files, the errors are still thrown for each input .eps image.  So does the image engine(s) wrapped into tex4ht not like .eps images?

Comment: you will need to configure it to use the windows name for the imagemagic convert program which is renamed as convert is a system command (as you show above) that is trying to reformat your disk... (fortunately it is unlikely that you pass valid convert options by mistake)

Comment: it is best to convert the `eps` images to either `svg` or `png` before the `tex4ht` conversion and to remove the `.eps` entry from `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions`. in this way the correct file will be used

Comment: @michal.h21 there is something fishy here imho. In html4.4ht there is line `\Needs{"convert \csname Gin@base\endcsname.eps \csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt"}`. I would expected this to map somehow to the convert section in tex4ht.env but actually it is a direct call to an executable.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `tex4ht.env` is used only for the DVI to output picture conversion, not for conversion between output formats. but the conversion command should be configurable, as is in the `PDF` configuration.

Comment: @michal.h21 Yes, copying the configuration and changing it enables the eps to svg conversion on windows. I could add an answer when the question is reopened for the direct problem, but if you have suggestion how to make it configurable it would be perhaps better if you do it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer no, it would be nice if you could post it, it can take some time before the configurable interface lands in TL :)

Comment: @michal.h21 ok added, feel free to edit if you think something should be done better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html4.4ht contains a configuration for graphics with a direct reference to a call to `convert`. If I copy this configuration to your `cfg` file and change it htlatex calls `magick convert` instead and  succeeds on windows:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.pdf,.svg,.png,.jpg}
\Configure{Picture}{.svg}
\Configure{graphics*}
   {eps}
   {\openin15=\csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt\relax%
   \ifeof15%
   \Needs{"magick convert \csname Gin@base\endcsname.eps \csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt"}%
   \fi%
   \closein15%
   {\Configure{Needs}{File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt}\Needs{}}%
   \Picture[\csname a:GraphicsAlt\endcsname]{{\csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt} \csname a:Gin-dim\endcsname
}}
\ifdefined\HCode\else .... \fi
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{14}{10}{8}
\ConfigureEnv{tabular}
    {\HCode{}}{\HCode{}}{}{}
\ConfigureEnv{figure}
    {\HCode{}}{\HCode{}}{}{}
\Configure{float}
   {\ifOption{refcaption}{}{\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar \leavevmode}}
   {\HCode{}}
{\ifvmode \IgnorePar \fi\EndP \HCode{}\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar}
\Css {body {margin-top: 100px;
                 margin-right: 400px;
                 margin-bottom: 10px;
                 margin-left: 400px;
                }
         }
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Comment: alternative command, which doesn't rasterize vecors is `"\Needs{epstopdf '\Gin@base.eps' '\Gin@base.pdf' && pdf2svg '\Gin@base.pdf' '\Gin@base.svg'"}`. but the `pdf2svg` command isn't installed by default, it must be installed by the user.

Comment: The above preamble will process .eps images, but for the .pdf images in converted_graphics, they just get passed over -- i.e. no recognition.   I tried adding an entire new `\Configure{graphics*} {pdf}` with the appropriate file extension but still passes over the .pdf and does not respond.  Also, in order to perform a complete image conversion, do the ImageMagick parameters like `-trim -density 110x110 -transparent #FFFFFF` need to be added into the preamble somewhere?

Comment: Don't use comments for follow-up questions. Ask a new question so that I'm not the only one to see it.